# "The superconstructor must be called first in the constructor body" magic

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs6, fla

I have a comparably big .fla file and sometimes, when I try to publish it I get `"The superconstructor must be called first in the constructor body."` error. It appears randomly, I can close Flash CS6 and then reopen it, publish again and then everything is fine, but why can it appear sometimes? It's just driving me crazy. Can anyone explain why is this happenning?

Comment: without seeing any code? little tricky. Could be a timing thing, one time it is ready next time it is not.

Comment: I don't think it's a timing issue, which generally occur at run time. This problem seems to be happening at compile time. You might look into ways to "clean" your .FLA file (like export it and import to a new FLA or something).

Comment: Thanks for helping Sunil, I'll try your method.